# Google Sheets filter view -- sort string before number

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image: Text]

Hi, I have this sample data of cast times for a game (Instant, 1.0, 2.0, 6.0  etc).  I'm trying to make a filter view just to sort (not exclude) -- "Instant" first, and the rest ascending.  So looking for

```
Instant
Instant
1.0
1.0
2.0
2.0
6.0
```

Tried a bunch of variations but I'm either getting no results or just Instant

`=regexmatch(D:D,"Instant|\d\.\d")`  <-- the "or" did nothing?  Gave me "Instant" rows

thanks

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: copied sheet to new workbook, only about 40 rows filled out but  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OihNG2FJYX6jHN6cWrbB4NL4xluwKxCuQEDCRZffsCw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need a helper column with formula on first row:

```
={""; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D2:D="",,IF(D2:D="Instant", 0.5, D2:D)))}
```

(you can set the font color to white)

[image]

### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Jp7_WjsuJflkPG401EnaB_fyoU-FFCODkhwEZ6Mperk/edit#gid=440098945)

Comment: i see the `={""; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D2:D="",,IF(D2:D="Instant", 0.5, D2:D)))}` in O1, but what did you set Filter1 to in the Filter View dialog?  It looks blank for me

Comment: oh, I think I see your plan of attack now.  A full column of data mimicking Cast column, but replacing "Instant" with "0.5", and then sorting that.  Hmmm, does work, but feels dirty =D

Comment: yes, its blank because you want to sort not filter out rows. you just sort it A-Z